# Why doesn't a SwiftUI transition work on a nested child view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and want to understand the transitions.

I assumed that the transition is something that will run whenever the view appears or disappears, irrelevant of the fact where the view is placed in the hierarchy. However, a simple example below shows that that's not the case:

```swift
public struct TransitionTestView: View {
    @State var isShown = false
    
    public init() {}
    
    public var body: some View {
        if isShown {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello!")
                    .font(.title)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading)) // Will NOT work!
            }
            .transition(.move(edge: .leading)) // Will work
        } else {
            Button("Show") {
                withAnimation {
                    isShown = true
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Can someone explain why is the inner transition on `Text` not working? It is also a view and is also appearing for the first time together with its parent. What if I have several `Text` children in `VStack` and want to set different transitions on them?